# Sending data to header.ejs using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I send data to my Nodejs pages doing something like:

```
res.render("mainPage.ejs",{myArray})
```

However, I have a situation where I want to change set the navbar dropdown values using some values form my database.

I wanted to know if is possibile to send data to every `header.ejs` file using Nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Like Handlebars, ejs also has the concept of partials.

Check out the official doc. here:
https://www.includehelp.com/node-js/ejs-partials.aspx

You can pass the data to the views by doing something like this:

```js
router.get('/routeHere', (req,res)=>{

res.render('pages/blog', 
{
 key1: value1,
key2: value2

 });

});
```

You will then be able to access the object under 'res.render()' in the view.

Comment: I am suing partial. My question was about how to send data to a partial

Answer (score 0):

You don't "send data to a partial". You pass data into your temaplate `res.render('mytemplate', { user })` and `user` is available to each partial you included in `mytemplate.ejs`. Included partials see their parent template data.